# Use data.table to store simulation results in loops

Tags: r, data.table

I am coming across a practical problem, where I have a `for` loop iterating `iter=500` times. In each iteration, a `12 *11` matrix is stored. One way I can think of to store those data is via an array `array(NA,c(12,11,500))`.

But I suspect this may be quite slow. Rather, is there more efficient way to do this? Like using `data.table`? I am not clear how to create a data.table to do this.

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ reproducible example (fewer iterations (2?) and smaller matrices/arrays/whateveroutput)

Comment: Create a list  : `my_list <- list()` Then store  each iteration  inside the list like  `my_list[[i]] <- my_matrix` where `i` is the iteration  step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your simulation the most efficient method is to store it directly in an `array` or `list`. The penalty is not storing in a pre-allocated array but the actual computation, so if you could perform all the simulations simultaneously that would likely be your big performance gain.

The (simplified) examples below

```
n <- 500
nsim <- 11 * 12
simfun <- rnorm
# lapply
sims <- lapply(seq_len(nsim), function(x)simfun(nsim))
# Pre-allocate
sims2 <- vector('list', n)
for(i in seq_len(n))
  sims2[[i]] <- simfun(nsim)
# array
sims3 <- array(dim = c(500, 11, 12))
for(i in seq_len(n))
 sims3[i,,] <- simfun(nsim)
# all at once (fastest)
sims4 <- array(simfun(nsim * n), dim = c(500, 11, 12))
```

should thus all be fine.